# Difference in hours and minutes between two datetimes MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I've a query in MySQL that is returning the difference between two datetimes. The problem is that the query is giving only the difference in hours.

Example:

Datetime1 is `2015-12-16 08:00:00` and datetime2 is `2015-12-16 10:45:00`

I want the difference to be returned as: `02:45:00` and not only `02:00:00`

My query is:

```
$query1 = "SELECT X, 
                  time_format(SUM(abs(timediff(datetime2, datetime1))),'%H:%m:%s') as SUM 
           FROM table1, table2 
           WHERE table1.Y = table2.Y 
             and DATE(datetime1) >= '$datepicker' 
             AND DATE(datetime1) <= '$datepicker1' 
           GROUP BY table.Y";
```

Comment: `timediff` should be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell your query syntax for working out the time difference is correct except for the formatting in the `time_format()`.

The format for minutes is `%i` and not `%m` so change to this and it should work as expected

```
time_format(SUM(abs(timediff(datetime2, datetime1))),'%H:%i:%s') as SUM 
                                                         ^^
```

Comment: Big fail from my side :(  Thanks for the answer. Props!

Comment: By the way, i'm having problems when i have more then one regist that contain hours and minutes. Example, regist 1 - datetime1 2015-12-16 08:00:00 datetime2 2015-12-16 12:30:00 and regist 2 - datetime1 2015-12-16 08:00:00 datetime2 2015-12-16 10:30:00 the result i get is "NULL" why's that?

P.S: I've figured it out. i added time_format(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(abs(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(datetime2, datetime1))))),'%H:%i:%s')

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
select timediff('2015-12-16 08:00:00','2015-12-16 10:45:00')
```

it is working.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Who upvoted this twaddle. How is this relevant to the question in any way.

Comment: i have added the answer of the example, we should focus on the conceptual aspect rather than looking for actual answer.

Comment: Good answers do not start with **try this**, they contain a reason for doing what you are suggesting. As the questioner was already doing **exactly** what you have coded where is the benefit in this answer and where is the edification in **trying this**

Comment: by trying this i mean you should try to use this rather than formatting date using mysql date format and playing with other function. if it solves the problem, developer will stick to it.

Comment: In that case say so in your answer!

Comment: @RiggsFolly, i agree on this. I should say your answer is, Thanks Amit